# How to extract float and integer that end with specific characters using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've the following XML (consider it as normal text) :

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="1.5sp" />
```

I'm using the following code to extract numbers, for example **15** and **1.5**:

```
let largeOutputResult = inputXML.replace(/(\d+)(sp|dp)/g, (_,num,end) => `${num*1.5}${end}`);
```

The issue I found is when I run the code, it extracts **15**, **1** and **5**, not **1.5**, how I can fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the decimal point in your regex (and say all the digits before it are also optional):

```js
const text = `\
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="1.5dp"
/>`;

const output = text.replace(/(\d*\.?\d+)(sp|dp)/g, (_, num, end) => `${num * 1.5}${end}`);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Massive thanks for your help, exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

You could also get a match only without groups.

```
\d*\.?\d+(?=[sd]p\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d*\.?\d+` Match optional digits, optional dot and 1+ digits (if you don't want to match only a leading dot only, then you can use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `[sd]p\b`  Match either the words `sp` or `dp` to the right
- `)` close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/okJeTr/1)

```js
const inputXML = `<ImageView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="1.5dp"
/>`;
const largeOutputResult = inputXML.replace(/\d*\.?\d+(?=[sd]p\b)/g, m => m * 1.5);
console.log(largeOutputResult);
```